# Ubuntu dualboot grub problem

Tags: grub2, 22.04

I used to install ubutun on a dualboot with windows. On this time I installed it with windows 11 on hp laptop. When I install and configure boot-repair to fix the boot anomaly, the grub works fine when I choose to go to Ubuntu but once I choose Windows boot manager and I go to Windows 11 when I turn it off and on the grub doesn't work anymore. How can I solve this problem

Comment: Just about every post with HP, says that efibootmgr change of boot order does not work with HP. Grub uses efibootmgr to change boot order. HP users have to go into UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu) and change boot order there. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2  Fix seems to be in the works. https://www.phoronix.com/news/HP-BIOSCFG-For-Linux-6.6